Get value in a key-value pair of an object inside nested array in MongoDB
Consider the sample data shown below. V1, V2 and V3 are unique identifiers for objects in the array values, these identifiers are only used once (i.e. there will never be two objects in the array values with the same id even when they belong to different arrays in the collection.)
db.experiment.deleteMany({});

db.experiment.insertMany([
  {
    'id': 'Q1',
    'statements': [
      {
        'property': 'P1',
        'values': [
          {'id': 'V1', 'value': 'Q1 foo'},
          {'id': 'V2', 'value': 'Q1 bar'}
        ]
      },
      {
        'property': 'P2',
        'values': [
          {'id': 'V3', 'value': 'Q1 baz'},
          {'id': 'V4', 'value': 'Q1 qux'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'id': 'Q2',
    'statements': [
      {
        'property': 'P1',
        'values': [
          {'id': 'V5', 'value': 'Q2 foo'},
          {'id': 'V6', 'value': 'Q2 bar'}
        ]
      },
      {
        'property': 'P2',
        'values': [
          {'id': 'V7', 'value': 'Q2 baz'},
          {'id': 'V8', 'value': 'Q2 qux'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]);

I want to get the field value in the object whose id is V3 in the top-level object whose id is Q1. That is, the expected result is shown below:
{
  _id: ObjectId(<object-id>),
  value: 'Q1 baz'
}

I was able to get the desired result by using the aggregate pipeline shown below.
printjson(db.experiment.aggregate([
  {
    '$match': {
      'id': 'Q1'
    }
  },
  // I used $unwind because I did not know how to use $filter in an
  // array that is inside another array.
  {
    '$unwind': '$statements'
  },
  // I used $project in order to use $filter
  {
    '$project': {
      'projectResult': {
        $filter: {
          input: '$statements.values',
          as: 'value',
          cond: { $eq: ["$$value.id", "V3"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // I used $match to filter out empty arrays.
  {
    '$match': {
      'projectResult': {$ne: []}
    }
  },
  // At this point, the key projectResult is an array, so I needed to
  // unwind it in order to $project the key "value"
  {
    '$unwind': '$projectResult'
  },
  {
    '$project': {
      'value': '$projectResult.value'
    }
  }
]))

[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('66e0a3f4370082960c2202d8'),
    value: 'Q1 baz'
  }
]

I am wondering if there's another way that uses fewer lines of codes or is more efficient. Using an aggregate query is not entirely necessary, as long as your code returns the expected return explained above, I would accept your answer.
These are one of the first aggregate queries that I write in MongoDB so I thought it would be better to ask to more experienced users for better ways to do this.

not necessarily short https://mongoplayground.net/p/tdQORDN1kSO

What happens if more than 1 statement has a value with id:V3?

@Joe There will never be 2 objects in the array values with the same id. I have edited the first paragraph in my question to make that clear.
